# Add a prefix to each element of an array in C

Tags: c, arrays

Hello making a small program that reads a text file then creates an ouput text file with the line number prefixed in front of the string.

Since the input file is called upon with fgets. I want to change the array of strings it is stored in before outputting it into the textile.

example Original File

```
Hello
How Are you?

good.
```

Output file

```
1 Hello
2 How Are you?
3
4 good.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The next step I wanted this program to take would to be not to print out blank lines. But as far as the original question I asked this works like a charm. Thanks for the insight @optimist.

```
 while( ( fgets( b, MAX, src ) ) != NULL )
 {
    linecount++;
    fprintf( dst, "%d: ", linecount );
     fputs( b, dst );


 }
```